# Pandas isin() returning all false

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm using pandas 1.1.3, the latest available with Anaconda.

I have two DataFrames, imported from a .txt and a .xlsx file. They have a column called "ID" which is an int64 (verified with df.info()) on both DataFrames.

df1:

```
          ID        Name
0 1234564567 Last, First
1 1234564569 Last, First
...
```

df2:

```
          ID Amount
0 1234564567  59.99
1 5678995545  19.99
```

I want to check if all of the IDs on df1 are on df2. For this I create a series:

```
foo = df1["ID"].isin(df2["ID"])
```

And I get that all values are `False`, even though manually I checked and the values do match.

```
0       False
1       False
2       False
3       False
4       False 
...
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, if there is something wrong with the environment, or if it is a known bug.

Answer (score 1):

You must do something wrong. Try to reproduce this error with a toy example as I did here. The below works for me.

Reproducing with and sharing a minimal example not only allows you to challenge your error but also allows us to provide help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick'], 'ID':[1234564567, 1234564569]} 
data2 = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick'], 'ID':[1234564567, 5678995545]} 
# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2) 
df["ID"].isin(df2["ID"])
0     True
1    False
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```

---

***EDIT:*** with Paul's data I don't get any error. See the importance of providing examples?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID':['1234564567', '1234564569'],'Name':['Last, First', 'Last, First']}
data2 = {'ID':['1234564567', '5678995545'],'Amount': [59.99, 19.99]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df["ID"].isin(df2["ID"])
0     True
1    False
```

Comment: You're right. It does work with that example. It might be related to the datatype or something similar. I'll check on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID':['1234564567', '1234564569'],'Name':['Last, First', 'Last, First']}
data2 = {'ID':['1234564567', '5678995545'],'Amount': [59.99, 19.99]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

now we have that set up we get to the meat...

```
df1["ID"].apply(lambda x: df2['ID'].isin([x]))
```

Which shows

```
    0       1
0   True    False
1   False   False
```

That ID 0 in df1 is in ID 0 of df2

Comment: with this data, the following works for me: `df["ID"].isin(df2["ID"])` see edits in my answer

Comment: agreed. I also wanted to show where they interested... Methinks I did too much...